# pandas: count the number of unique occurrences of each element of list in a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, count

I have a dataframe containing a column of lists lie the following:

```
df
     pos_tag
0    ['Noun','verb','adjective']
1    ['Noun','verb']
2    ['verb','adjective']
3    ['Noun','adverb']
...
```

what I would like to get is the number of time each unique element occurred in the overall column as a dictionary:

```
desired output:
my_dict = {'Noun':3, 'verb':3, 'adjective':2, 'adverb':1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) along with [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
freq = df['pos_tag'].explode().value_counts().to_dict()
```

Result:

```
# print(freq)
{'Noun':3, 'verb':3, 'adjective':2, 'adverb':1}
```

Answer (score 1):

For improve performance use `Counter` with flatten values of nested lists:

```
from collections import Counter

my_dict = dict(Counter([y for x in df['pos_tag'] for y in x]))
print (my_dict)
{'Noun': 3, 'verb': 3, 'adjective': 2, 'adverb': 1}
```